# spring framework mongodb query criteria to match all element in array

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

community,

I'm working with MongoDB and spring boot. I need to generate a query that allows me to match all object in an array of embedded documents. I know how to generate the query in MongoDB, but it is a very big query to build it in raw way, specifically I need to find the way to generate in spring-boot something like this:

```
db.getCollection("user").find(
    { 
        "userSkills" : {
            "$all" : [
                {
                    "$elemMatch" : {
                        "skill.name" : /java/i
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
);
```

I already tried to achieve it using

```
org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria
```

but it does not work passing elemMatch Criteria to Criteria.all() method 
Thanks for you time

Comment: can you also write document structure as well?

Comment: Thanks ;), I already found a way to do it
    `Criteria.where("userSkills").elemMatch(Criteria.where("skill.name").regex("Java", "i").and("skill.level").gte(5)elemMatch(Criteria.where("skill.name").regex("Python", "i").and("skill.level").gte(5)`